# IntelliJ not seeing my golang tests package

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a directory structure like this.

```
/home/senthil/greeting]$ tree
.
|-- hello.go
`-- hello_test.go
```

Hello.go

```
package greeting

// Hello returns "Hello World - <name>"
func Hello(name string) string {
    return "Hello World - " + name
}
```

And hello_test.go

```
package greeting

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    hello := Hello("Hello")
    expected := "Hello"
    if hello != expected {
        t.Errorf("Expected %s, got %s", expected, hello)
    }
}
```

1. I can run the tests with `go test -v`
2. But I cannot run the tests directly from my IntelliJ.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was missing a go.mod file. I had to add a file called `go.mod`

with the contents.

```
module greeting

go 1.16
```

Now, I can exercise the tests from IntelliJ.